# What is the stablished value for the modularity of the Karate Club?

Tags: graph-theory, python, random-graphs, network

The question speaks for itself. In the literature, we find that the karate club graph has a modularity value of 0.42. A python library to compute the modularity is networkx. To obtain the modularity of a graph we need to run the Louvain Community Detection Algorithm (LCDA). I provide a code snipped for reproducibility:

```
!pip install networkx
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.community import louvain_communities, modularity
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

def seed_run(seed, runs=100):
  communities_lcda = []
  results_lcda = []
  Ncomms = 0
  for i in range(runs):
    communities_lcda.append(louvain_communities(G, seed=seed, resolution=1))
    results_lcda.append(modularity(G,communities_lcda[i]))
    Ncomms += len(communities_lcda[i])/100
  results_lcda = np.array(results_lcda)
  return results_lcda.mean(), results_lcda.std()/np.sqrt(runs)

results = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(seed_run)(seed, runs=100) for seed in range(10000))

results_mod = np.array(results)[:,0]
target = 0.42
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.plot(results_mod, 'o')
```

It can take a while to run all the 10000 seeds. In the original reference it is mentioned that the node ordering can influence the results so we would not be surprised to see some variability. However, we find it strange that everyone is reporting a modularity of 0.42. What are we doing wrong? Or maybe, what is happending inside networkx that we can't see?

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.community.louvain.louvain_communities.html#networkx.algorithms.community.louvain.louvain_communities

[Scatter plot of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHN0U.png)

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a question. You have a source saying they got 0.42. You have a calculation that gives you many values, all close to 0.42. You have a reason to expect some variability in the answer you got. What else needs to be explained?

Comment: Well, the mean and standard deviation are 0.440 and 0.008. We agree that it's not super far from the supposed true value of 0.42, yet, it seems to be significantly higher (In the plot, the modularities cluster around 0.445). Take into account that people are competing to find the algorithm that maximizes this modularity value, so even 2 decimals might end up to be key.

Comment: Maybe the one time that someone tried LCDA on this graph, they got unlucky, and everyone else copied their results. Maybe $0.42$ is what you get with the standard node ordering (and looping through the nodes in a standard way). Does the calculation for $0.42$ that you're trying to reproduce give the partition that results in that modularity value?

Comment: Yes... We also thought about this possibility. The partitions look in all cases and as far as we hahve been able to see they are the same when the modularity is .42. Maybe you answer is the only possible one. I will migrate this question to the NetworkX repository. I will Provide a link to the issue if they solve or comment about it. Thanks!